# Is there a way to make the FILTER in Google Sheets ignore the first matching result?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I'm completely new to Google Sheets and any other spreadsheet-related software.

I'm attempting to format the results of a Google Form into a easier-to-view format.

So far, I've been able to get most of the things I needed (such as filtering the information into the correct spots in a different sheet and using the dropdowns as a criteria to filter the results), however, I need to have the sheet show two diferent results in different sections, like this:[exmaple of the sheet's displayed information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Pcx.png)

Based on what the sheet will be doing, and the way the filters I've placed works, I just need to have the second 'section' of the sheet (use the image above as a reference for sections) ignore the first matching results from the filter, but I don't know how to parse that into a string which would work.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UjAbXsPf9mhZGKbrpcZ6QT2qHovHvt6SI4bsFdn6ezM/edit?usp=sharing This is the sheet template, feel free to look, edit and include comments.

If you have any suggestions on how I can improve the logic I used, and how can I have the thing I'm having issues resolved would be awesome. Again, I'm completely new to google sheet, excel, etc... So I'm just figuring everything out haha.